# Is this an anti-pattern or is this ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have something like the following:

```
exercise.log_entries.for_user(@user).for_date(date)
```

Is this really bad code for Rails? I can't do @user.log_entries because it needs to be scoped to a specific exercise.

Is this considered ok or really bad? How would you refactor?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using that for access controls, then I would say it's probably a little smelly, though I wouldn't complain too loudly about it. The concern is that not leading off with your access controls means that future refactoring might end up breaking those controls, which would be embarrassing at the least.

How are your associations set up? Would something like this be possible?

```
@user.log_entries.for_exercise(exercise).for_date(date)
```

Comment: Yeah absolutely. So it's better to start with the user first? It's basically the same thing but just reversed... And it's not so much access controls as it is scoping over an iteration. Have a workout. Then exercise_workout's which uniquely scope an exercise to a workout associated to a user and then a user has log entries against that exercise.